# difference between graded ring and its twisted global sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, graded-rings

Let $S_{\bullet}$ be a graded ring, generated in degree $1$ with $S_0 = k$ (a field). One can associate to $S_{\bullet}$ the twisted graded ring
$$
\Gamma_{\bullet} = \left( \ \Gamma(\mathrm{Proj} S_{\bullet}, \mathcal{O}(n)) \  \right)_{n \geq 0},
$$
where $\mathcal{O}(n)$ is the standard twisting sheaf on $\mathrm{Proj} S_{\bullet}$. It is known that $S_{\bullet}$ and $\Gamma_{\bullet}$ must be isomorphic *from some degree on* as graded $S_{\bullet}$-modules.

> I am looking for a simple example where $S_{\bullet}$ and $\Gamma_{\bullet}$ are not isomorphic in every degree.

Comment: Take $S=k[x^4,x^3y,xy^3,y^4]$ (with the obvious grading). Then check $\Gamma= S[x^2y^2]$.